# Insert into multiple tables on one transaction using GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to store information in 3 tables in a single transaction using GORM. I need to create just one row on Table1 and Table2 and multiple records on Table3

```
type Table1 struct {
    Id          uuid.UUID   `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
}

type Table2 struct {
    Id          uuid.UUID   `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Table2ID    uuid.UUID   `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Table2      Table2
}

type Table3 struct {
    Id          uuid.UUID   `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Table3ID    uuid.UUID   `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Table3      Table3
}

type Table3List []Table3
```

When I use just Table2 including all Table1 attributes, that works. One transaction creates one row in each table., but if I use Table3List, GORM creates multiple records on Table 1, table 2, and didn't assign Table3ID on Table3. I tried to create an aditional logical struct (is not a DB table) like this, but doesn't work

```
type MyCompoundedTx struct {
    Table2
    Table3List
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you are approaching transactions in GORM not the proper way. Documentation https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html#Transaction is quite clear how to do transactions including many queries.

Comment: @BartoszGrzybowsk i I'm wondering if I can define some kind of struct to store the information in the 3 tables with db.Create(&MyStruct). This works for 2 tables when I use db.Create(&Table2)

Comment: I don't really think it's supported feature of GROM and what you are seeing is a side effect of some kind. It would be best to create those things the way GROM docs advise to do. If you need one struct you could just put three models and call Create for each struct's field db.Create(&struct.ModelA) etc

Comment: @BartoszGrzybowski That feature is documented here: 
https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Auto-Create-x2F-Update https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Create-With-Associations

Comment: yes, but it's for tables with relations. Do you have those set up?